# What is $_[0] ,$_[1] in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am a Java developer, and I have been given Ruby code to understand and later to work on.

I went through the Ruby tutorials on tutorialspoint.com but I can't figure out what `$_[0]` is.

It is being assigned to a variable in the code, and it is definitely not a command-line argument because I wrote code to test that and it failed.
So, can anyone say what the significance of it is?

Comment: While Ruby supports many "magic" variables, the use of them is controversial, and, as you see, somewhat of a maintenance issue because they are obscure. I'd recommend looking at the English module for more readable names of the variables.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's one of the magic variables.

`$_` holds value of the last line read from standard input. `$_[0]` is, therefore, first symbol of that string.

See [English.rb](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/English.rb) for more magic variables

```
# The last line read by <tt>Kernel.gets</tt> or
# <tt>Kernel.readline</tt>. Many string-related functions in the
# +Kernel+ module operate on <tt>$_</tt> by default. The variable is
# local to the current scope. Thread local.
alias $LAST_READ_LINE          $_
```

Comment: Although it's a magic variable it's not actually global. The `$` is misleading.

Comment: Yepp, most of the "magic globals" are actually "magic thread-locals".

Answer (score 5):

`$_` - string last read by `gets`

`[0]` is of course, indexing into that string.

http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/globalvars.html